# Can't instantiate class error in JSF, caused by NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Here is my managed Bean class,

```
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {

    private PieChartModel pieModel;

    public ChartBean(){
        createPieModel(); 
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {  
        return pieModel;  
    }  

    private void createPieModel(){  
        try {
            pieModel = new PieChartModel();  

            String query = "SELECT b.countryname,count(b.countryname) FROM info.summery a,info.countrymcc b;";
            Connector conn = new Connector();
            Statement str = (Statement) conn.getConn().createStatement();
            ResultSet res = str.executeQuery(query);


            while(res.next()){

                  pieModel.set(res.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2)));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChartBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
}
```

But the problem is when it is compiled it gives an error like this "Cant instantiate class: org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean". What is the reason??

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at  

org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean.createPieModel(ChartBean.java:45) at     
org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean.<init>(ChartBean.java:32) at     
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at     
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorI‌​    
mpl.java:39) at     
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA‌​    
ccessorImpl.java:27) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) at    
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) at java.lang.Class
```

Comment: Try to not do everything in the constructor. remove the call to createPieModel() from the constructor and annotate createPieModel()  with @PostConstruct

Comment: I'll try it.then it gives an error like this, "An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean chartBean".

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM model even with Java EE like JPA or Hibernate?

Comment: What is at line 45 and 32? org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean.createPieModel(ChartBean.java:45) at org.primefaces.examples.view.ChartBean.<init>(ChartBean.java:32) at I don't know if the source you provide is the full one. So I'm unable to tell what line 45 is

Answer (score 2):

By a process of elimination, the problem is happening because `conn.getConn()` is returning `null`.  You should be able to simply confirm that the exception occurs at that line (by checking the line number!), and we know that `conn` cannot be `null`, so it must be result of `getConn()` that is `null`.

That's about as far as I can go without knowing what the `Connector` class is and how its `getConn()` method works.

---

For the record, here's how I eliminated other possibilities.

The NPE is being thrown in the `createPieModel` call ... and not in some method called from `createPieModel`:

```
1. private void createPieModel(){  
2.     try {
3.         pieModel = new PieChartModel();  
4.         String query = "SELECT b.countryname,count(b.countryname) FROM info.summery a,info.countrymcc b;";
5.         Connector conn = new Connector();
6.         Statement str = (Statement) conn.getConn().createStatement();
7.         ResultSet res = str.executeQuery(query);
8.         while(res.next()){
9.             pieModel.set(res.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2)));
10.        }
11.    } catch (SQLException ex) {
12.        Logger.getLogger(ChartBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
13.    }
14. }
```

- It cannot be line 3 because any NPE would be thrown in the constructor.
- It cannot be line 4
- It cannot be line 5 - see line 3
- It *could* be line 6
- It cannot be line 7 - because `str` must be non-null (if we get that far)
- It cannot be line 8 - because `executeQuery` never returns `null`
- It cannot be line 9 - because `res` and `pieModel` must be non-null.
- It cannot be line 12 - because nothing there can return a `null`.

Hence it can *only* happen on line 6.

Comment: I'm not sure what is returning conn.getConn(). But if it's creating a database connection the Exception should be `SQLException`, not `nullPointerException`.

I agree with you in that it seems the exception is happening in `conn.getConn()`, maybe OP should revise his code.